# Convert APIGateway Resource Pollicy output to JSON Format

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

Want to parse the apigateway policy output from sdk call to json format to retrive the data.

```
require 'aws-sdk-apigateway'
require 'json'

client = Aws::APIGateway::Client.new()

resp = client.get_rest_api({
  rest_api_id: "rwxo2fldcl"
})

bpset = resp.policy

JSON.parse(bpset)
```

Comment: Getting the error $ ruby api.rb
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 784: unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it after removing backslash() from the result.

```
temp = bpset.delete('\\')

arr = JSON.parse(temp)
```